# going to build a php MVC, what naming conventions do i need to be aware of?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm pretty new to OO PHP, however i get how it all works and am ready to start building an MVC for a big site i'm working on. I know it isnt necessary written that *you must do it like this* but there's gotta be some normal practises....

class names - camelcase? underscores?

class files - same as class?

url/post/get controll name - router.php?

any other things i should be aware of before i embark?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't really matter how you name things as long as you are consistent.

If you are interested in taking a look at coding standards:

- [Zend Framework Coding Standard for PHP](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.html)
- [PEAR Coding Standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php)
- [Horde Coding Standards](http://www.horde.org/horde/docs/?f=CODING_STANDARDS.html)

Comment: The folder structure convention used by Zend Framework is the one used by PEAR. As you said, be consistent.

Comment: ZF link moved here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html

Answer (score 1):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html
Should be your bible as a PHP developer.

Answer (score 1):

Class constants are generally all uppercase, Class names are generally like java with capital first letters `SomeClassName`

Beyond that, I guess it depends who you ask

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332831/php-best-practices-for-naming-conventions/332854#332854

It's not at all what you asked, but do consider looking at one of the literally dozens and dozens of existing MVC-style PHP frameworks. You can save yourself a lot of time and generally get better quality if you use a solid existing framework.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of MVC logic, at least separate your control and presentation. I'm working with Wordpress, which looks extremely horrible in places, especially admin side. For my own part, I have the controller validate the $_REQUEST, make changes to the data by interacting with the database, and then instantiate an appropriate view class.

Answer (score 1):

Preferred Directory Structure: My/Class.php

ClassNames: My_Class

If you are using a modular MVC structure, make sure you have the namespace included in your bootstrap.php [this is Zend Framework specific, but I imagine there must be something similar for other mvc frameworks).

what else...the views naming - the default is dropDownAction() becomes drop-down.phtml in Zend Views.